# How do I store data for particular user only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to store society maintenance bill to be stored in every users data node.So i can access them if required. I wanted to update the already exist record with new record but I don't know how do i get particular record if firebase generate random keys. Here I have commented the line where my data are being pushed. What will I do to save and retrieve data in such way as `firebase realtime database` generate auto generated push key for every record?

This is my code which I wanted to store in particular user node:

```
 handleSubmitFirebase(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    this.billrange = this.billto.value + "-" + this.billfrom.value;
    var counter = 0;
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    var today = new Date();
    var  date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var currMonth = monthNames[today.getMonth()];
    var curryear = today.getFullYear();

    this.state.userInput.forEach(user => {

        var billInfo = {
            bill_eml: user.email,
            bill_name:user.first_name,
            bill_due_date: this.billdue.value,
            bill_period: this.billrange,
            status: this.status.value,
            total:this.state.Total,
            bill_id: DbConfig.database().ref('billing').push(billInfo).key
        }; //user info


     //  DbConfig.database().ref('users').child(curryear).child(currMonth).push(billInfo)  this will generate new data node
       this.renderBillInput();
       console.log( this.state.billInput);
        this.state.billInput.forEach(bid => {

            var billId = {
                bill_id: bid.bill_id,
            }; //user info
            console.log(billId);
        });
    });
   //alert('submit'+JSON.stringify(billInfo));
   alert('Bill Generates Successfully') ;
    this.bill_nm.value = ''; // <- clear the input
    this.billdue.value = '';
    this.status.value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see in your code, the data structure is:

```
users: {
  "$year": {
    "$month": {
        bill_eml: "...",
        bill_name: "...",
        bill_due_date: "...",
        bill_period: "...",
        status: "...",
        total: ...,
        bill_id: "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your current data structure you can easily load all the bills for a specific year or a specific month within that year. There is no way to query all bills for a specific user in this structure without simply loading all bills and filtering in your application code.

It is very common in NoSQL databases that you have to modify your data model to allow the use-cases that you want for your app. For example: if you want to allow listing the bills for a specific user, you could modify the existing data structure to store the bills per user:

```
users: {
  "$uid": {
    "$year": {
      "$month": {
          bill_eml: "...",
          bill_name: "...",
          bill_due_date: "...",
          bill_period: "...",
          status: "...",
          total: ...,
          bill_id: "..."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can get the bills for a specific user by loading `/users/$uid`.

But of course with this modified structure it is now no longer possible to get the bills for all users for a specific month. If you want both use-cases (all bills for a specific user, all bills for all users for a specific month) you may need to duplicate some of the data. For example:

```
users: {
  "$uid": {
    "$year": {
      "$month": {
      }
    }
  }
}
months: {
  "$year": {
    "$month": {
  }
}
```

If you're new to this sort of data structure, I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/). And if you're coming from a more traditional relational database background, I recommend watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).